# How to make some part of text bold and some part of text normal in both EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-gui, textstyle

I want to make something like

wow its **cool** app

in android. so that users can see a bold text in both `TextView` and `EditText` like `WhatsApp`. I don't know what to do. I searched and found something in which we can use HTML tags but some of the users don't know how to use that. Is there a way so that it is easy for users to make some part of text bold and remaining will normal.

Here is the image which will clear more

[image]

in this image, users can bold some part of text by enclosing that in *'s.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For you to make text bold?  Place it in a StyleSpan with a bold style to it.  For the user to make it bold?  You'll have to provide some UI for them to do that, that isn't built in.

Comment: can you provide more detail

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTML code and set to textview or edittextview as following..

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String first = "Hello what's up ";
String next = "<B>some bold text </B>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));
```

if you want to add bold text after '*' character then find that character from textview or edittextview and apply  tag after '*' this character and set text into textview and edittextview